# redirect www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, redirection

We currently have a domain that have a wildcard ssl so our site is something like this,

```
www.ourdomain.com
ourdomain.com
subdomainA.ourdomain.com
subdomainB.ourdomain.com
```

and so on. What i want to ask is how to forward this,

```
www.subdomain.ourdomain.com to subdomain.ourdomain.com
```

I found this solution [cname redirection](https://www.dyncommunity.com/questions/43822/how-to-redirect-wwwsubdomaindomaincom-to-subdomain-1.html) but to no avail.
I also tried adding

```
www.subdomain
```

as an A record pointing to our domain IP but still doesn't work. It still not forwarding to the right subdomain without the "www.".

I also tried via .htaccess [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469508/htaccess-redirect-www-subdomain-domain-com-to-subdomain-domain-com) but before my .htaccess do it's job the TLS handshake already detects that our ssl doesn't handle 4th level domains, and it will show security error. So clearly .htaccess won't work.

Hope you guys can help, Thanks.

Comment: You should describe you have already done in more details and especially what "still doesn't work" mean.

Comment: Either way you do it, if you want redirection with valid SSL, you will need a certificate for `www.subdomain.ourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that a wildcard TLS certificate `*.example.com` will not be accepted as valid for `*.*.example.com`. The <kbd>*</kbd> in a wildcard certificate should match 1 or more **non-dot characters**.

In other words visitors to `https://www.subdomain.example.com` will always get a security warning for an invalid certificate BEFORE they can establish a connection to your web server and thus they will never be redirected to `https://subdomain.example.com`  regardless of how you attempt to redirect them.  (Unless they click away a number of different errors/warnings).